Terraform - AWS KMS Key
I am working with a Terraform workspace that includes both a single-region KMS key and global resources, such as IAM roles. We're now expanding the project to multiple regions. Based on AWS documentation, I understand that I cannot modify the existing KMS key to be multi-region. Tt must be created that way initially.
To adapt to this, I need to split the global resources from the regional ones without impacting the existing resources in the primary region.
I see two possible approaches:
1)Create a new workspace for the global resources: If I move global components (like IAM roles) to a new workspace, would I need to update the state of this new workspace to prevent Terraform from erroring or from recreating the existing resources in AWS?

Leave the global resources in the current workspace and separate the regional resources into a new workspace: If I go this route, would I need to modify the state to ensure existing resources, like the KMS key, aren’t deleted or duplicated?

What is the best approach to achieve this multi-region setup while ensuring that existing resources remain unchanged? Any guidance on managing the state effectively for either option would be appreciated.

You ask if moving resources to a different workspace requires modifying the state of that workspace. If you are talking about Terraform workspaces, then all those really are is a state file. If you "move something to a different workspace" then you are modifying the state of the workspace, that's literally the action you are performing. So yes, to move something to a workspace, you are definitely going to need to modify the state of the workspace (terraform import in the new workspace, terraform state rm in the old workspace).

Thank you. The reason I ask is because the state file is very large, and manually removing modules or resources looks error-prone. Is this the only way to accomplish this, or is there a more efficient approach to manage the state and split resources safely? Any guidance on handling this transition would be much appreciated.

To add:In my organization, we use a custom version of Terraform commands, so I’m not certain if import is supported. If it isn’t, is manually updating the state file my only option?

It could work with an import block maybe.

If your company uses a custom version of Terraform that you aren't even sure supports import, then how are we to know what other features your version supports or doesn't support? It sounds like you need to be talking to someone in your company that is responsible for maintaining that custom version of Terraform, instead of asking random strangers on the Internet with no knowledge of your company's custom Terraform implementation for help.
